# Looking for a simple Blockchain PoC to implement on a office level

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum

In order to put the Blockchain Technology research I've done in the span of a month in use, I'm looking forward to solve some simple everyday problem that we face in office in order to generate the PoC of Blockchain(It may contain solving the existing problem's solution for betterment as well...).

Any good suggestions for the problem-statement as the opinion I have is that, not every problem can be solved using blockchain. Please Correct me if I'm wrong.
(I'm priority wise looking for Ethereum Platform but open to use other platforms as well if that solves the problem in better way...)

Comment: By PoC, do you mean Proof of Concept?

Comment: Yes.absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger has been [collecting](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/groups/requirements/use-case-inventory) some use cases, though not all are fleshed out. You are correct that not every problem is suited to being solved by use of a blockchain.

Blockchain should be considered when you have a process that involves multiple parties, that don't necessarily trust one another, or a process that is subject to fraud and abuse. Some processes that can be improved by sharing data might be suitable for blockchain, however, within a single org, a distributed database can also suffice.

Comment: `If you need to use a blockchain at home or in a relationship...you need to find a new home / relationship`

Answer (score 0):

Well, It depends on your use case like what kind of PoC you're looking for, I have worked on two PoCs one built on `Hyperledger Fabric` and the other one is built on `Hyperledger Sawtooth`, you can check them out by visiting the below urls:

Hyperledger Fabric PoC: http://avocado.thoughtchimps.com

Hyperledger Sawtooth PoC: https://airplane.thoughtchimps.com

Hope this helps.